# How to store Google Auth Credentials object in Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, google-tag-manager, google-authentication, oauth2client

I'm trying integrate Google Tag Manager into my project. In official document, Google suggests oauth2client library. Unfortunately, this library deprecated. I used google_auth_oauthlib. I can get token and send request to Google Tag Manager API with this token. But I don't decide how can I store credentials object in Django. In oauth2client lib, there is CredentialsField for model. We can store Credentials object in this field with using DjangoORMStorage. But I can't use this deprecated library. Are there any alternative ways?

Google Tag Manager document is [here](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/api/v1/devguide)

My codes here:

```
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import Flow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

FLOW = Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
    settings.GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRETS_JSON,
    scopes=[settings.GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SCOPE])

class GTMAuthenticateView(APIView):
    def get(self,request,**kwargs):
        FLOW.redirect_uri = settings.GOOGLE_OAUTH2_REDIRECT_URI
        authorization_url, state = FLOW.authorization_url(access_type='offline',
        include_granted_scopes='true')
        return Response({'authorization_url':authorization_url,'state':state})

    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        FLOW.fetch_token(code=request.data['code'])
        credentials = FLOW.credentials
        return Response({'token':credentials.token})

class GTMContainerView(APIView):
    def get(self,request,**kwargs):
        service = get_service()
        containers = self.get_containers(service)
        return Response({'containers':str(containers),'credentials':str(FLOW.credentials)})

    @staticmethod
    def get_containers(service):
        account_list = service.accounts().list().execute()
        container_list = []
        for account in account_list['account']:
            containers = service.accounts().containers().list(parent=account["path"]).execute()
            for container in containers["container"]:
                container["usageContext"] = container["usageContext"][0].replace("['", "").replace("']", "")
                container_list.append(container)
        return container_list

def get_service():
    try:
        credentials = FLOW.credentials
        service = build('tagmanager', 'v2', credentials=credentials)
        return service
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking into this topic for a while but there don't seem to be any out ouf the box solutions (besides the one provided in the old oauth2client lib). Almost all documentation available online rely on storing credentials on disk storage, a method that I do not like at all. So basically I ended up creating my own model that stores the relevant information from the credentials object, with some helper class methods to quickly store and retrieve credentials from the database.

I include the relevant code, just in case anyone finds it useful. I'm using this to interact with the youtube api BTW, but the authorization part is oblivious to this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials

class GoogleCredential(models.Model):

    #In my case, I don't find necessary to store scopes in the DB
    #even though they are required information in the credentials object
    #So I just save it as a static var and inject it in the object
    #during the retrieval
    SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube", ]

    token = models.CharField(null=False)
    refresh_token = models.CharField(null=False)
    token_uri = models.CharField(null=False)
    client_id = models.CharField(null=False)
    client_secret = models.CharField(null=False)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @classmethod
    def store_credentials(cls, credentials, user):
        credentials = GoogleCredential.objects.get_or_create(user=user)[0]
        credentials.token = credentials.token
        credentials.refresh_token = credentials.refresh_token
        credentials.token_uri = credentials.token_uri
        credentials.client_id = credentials.client_id
        credentials.client_secret = credentials.client_secret
        credentials.user = user
        credentials.save()
        return credentials

    @classmethod
    def get_credentials(cls, user):
        try:
            user_credentials = GoogleCredential.objects.get(user=user)
            credentials = Credentials(
                token=user_credentials.token,
                refresh_token=user_credentials.refresh_token,
                token_uri=user_credentials.token_uri,
                client_id=user_credentials.client_id,
                client_secret=user_credentials.client_secret,
                scopes=GoogleCredential.SCOPES
            )
        except Exception as ex:
            credentials = None
        return credentials
```

Example view that stores the credentials:

```
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import Flow
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from .models import GoogleCredential

class YourAuthCallbackView(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        flow = Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
            get_secrets_file_path(),
            scopes=GoogleCredential.SCOPES,
            redirect_uri=request.build_absolute_uri('..')
        )
        path = request.get_full_path()
        flow.fetch_token(
            authorization_response=request.build_absolute_uri(path)
        )

        GoogleCredential.store_credentials(
            flow.credentials, 
            request.user
        )

        return redirect('/whatever')
```

Example view that uses the credentials in an api request:

```
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import Flow
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from .models import GoogleCredential

class YoutubeGetProfile(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        credentials = GoogleCredential.get_credentials(request.user)
        if credentials is not None:
            flow = Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
                get_secrets_file_path(),
                scopes=GoogleCredential.SCOPES,
                redirect_uri=request.build_absolute_uri('...')
            )
            youtube_api = build('youtube', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
            request = youtube_api.channels().list(part='snippet,contentDetails,statistics', mine=True)
            response = request.execute()
            #...
    return redirect('/whatever')
```

Answer (score -1):

Just switch over to Django 2
**pip install Django==2.2.12**
I did it and works fine